# Would WebClient.DownloadString work as if a user is browsing the website?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Basically I am downloading string/source of an online forum with threads/topics per page. But as a user, when I use a browser and browse through the site by clicking `n` number of links, it sometimes tells me that the server is too busy with an empty page with no topics.

Would I encounter the same thing if I try to access the same website `n` number of times by using `WebClient.DownloadString()`?

Would it be able to identify that my program is trying to access the website intensively?

Although it's not a high profile website like yahoo, google, etc, so it most likely doesn't have sophisticated algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same rules and limitations are going to be impacted for a call via WebClient.DownloadString as you would see as a user browsing the site.

If the server is too busy, or if the server has some sort of throttling or other system in place, it will still apply to your calls via this method.